# Is it polite to say "I have a question for you"?

Tags: questions, politeness

I'm not a native speaker. I've seen it a lot, but I'm not sure in which situations it's proper. Does it sound like a teacher asking a question to a student? Is it polite to say that if you are asking someone like a teacher to you? Sometimes I want to ask a question to a specific person in a group chat with @, if that person is senior to me, is it polite to say "I have a question for you"?

I forgot to mention that the group chat was for work, where we discuss technical issues and raise questions at experts, so not all the members in the group are familiar with each other, and it's only active when someone asks a question, which is not very frequent. So I think it sounds a little abrupt to bring up a question directly @ someone. Usually, I begin with "Hi (name), I have a question for you." and then I ask my question.

Comment: It works well for a peer-to-peer communication. Not polite enough, but depends on the situation.

Comment: So it stills sounds a little curt or patronizing, doesn't it? Is there a better alternative to that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit on Interpersonal Skills.SE.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to ask your question.

In many circumstances, it's best to proceed straight to the question.  If you're addressing a stranger, you might start the interaction with "Excuse me", as in "Excuse me, do you know where I can find a laundrette?" or "Excuse me, which way is it to the station, please?".  You wouldn't say "Excuse me, I have a question for you" - they just want you to get on it with it.

Where a question isn't necessarily expected, which may apply to some group chats, or where you don't want to launch abruptly straight into the question, it may be appropriate to introduce your question (or implicitly ask permission to ask it) with "I have a question for you".  There is nothing impolite about this at all.

Another mechanism is "May I ask you a question?".  On the face of it, this is more polite, but in some cases it may suggest that you intend to ask a personal question or a question that the addressee might not want to answer.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very comprehensive. It's just the second circumstance you mentioned that prompted this question of mine.

Comment: And I agree with you in the third circumstance you mentioned. It doesn't seem proper to bring up a question like that in a group chat, especially for work or discussion.

Comment: It should also be noted that 'I have a question **for you**' (rather than just 'I have a question') should be used only when there is something about the question that makes it specially apropriate to address it to that person.